# change the degree value in graph using degreeview in Networkx

Tags: python, graph, networkx, degrees

I am trying to change the value of degree of a particular node in graph, using degreeview in Networkx, like below:

```
G.degree[v[0]] = G.degree[v[0]]-1
```

Bout I keep getting this error:

> TypeError: 'DegreeView' object does not support item assignment.

Can someone please help me to know how to change the degree value in graph using degreeview?

Comment: The degree of a node is a characteristic of the node (number of edges adjacent to the node). So you can't change the degree (that's why it is a view), you have to change the graph (i.e., remove an adjacent edge).

Answer (score 1):

If you are working in construction and you're given a piece of wood 2 meters long, but you need one that's 1.5m long, you aren't going to just say "I assign its length to be 1.5m" and start to use it.  That won't change the measured length of the wood. You actually have change the piece of wood itself.  You have to cut the wood.  You have to change the thing that '2m' is measuring.

Here you've got basically the same problem.  It tells you the degree is, say 7, and you want to say the degree is 6.  You can't just do that by saying `G.degree[v[0]] = G.degree[v[0]] - 1` because the degree is measuring the number of edges of `v[0]`.  You have to actually get in there and change the graph itself.  To reduce the degree by 1, you'll have to remove an edge.